# Can you access files on the remote FTP server with RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, ftp, inputstream, apache-commons-net, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to read the file on the FTP remote-server using Apache Commons Net library.

`retrieveFileStream` returns `InputStream` and put it in `BufferedReader`.

But, I want to use `RandomAccessFile` (to use the `seek()` method).

I want to get `Inputstream` as a `RandomAccessFile`.

Is it possible?

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
InputStream in = ftp.retrieveFileStream(remote_file_name);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to starting reading the remote file from a certain offset, use [`FTPClient.setRestartOffset`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setRestartOffset(long)). The FTP server needs to support `REST` command (most do).

```
ftp.setRestartOffset(offset);
InputStream in = ftp.retrieveFileStream(remote_file_name);
// Now you can read as many bytes as you need from 'in'
```

If you do not want to read the file to the end, and you want to reuse the connection for other operations, you need to call [`FTPClient.abort`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#abort()).

---

*(You cannot convert `InputStream` to `RandomAccessFile`, nor use `RandomAccessFile` anyhow with files on FTP server)*